# Create Document with Script by Function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is there a way to create a Google Document (with included Script!) by a Google Script Function?
I have a Google Spreadsheet in which I have a menu point that allows me to create a document with this code:

```
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getRow()
var col = 3
var titletranslation = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, col).getValue()
var translation = Browser.inputBox(titletranslation , 'Please enter the translation here', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL)
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
doc = DocumentApp.create(translation);
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row, 6).setValue(doc.getUrl())
```

Now i want to build in, that the Document has its own Script, but I didn't manage to add a script via another script to the created Document. Does anybody know if this is possible and how?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Take a look at the Apps Script API.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you have to set in order to achieve your end goal. I will list them so you can follow them step by step:

1) In your Apps Script project go to *View* -> *Show manifest file*.

2) Open the `appscript.json` file that appeared and Paste this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.projects",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
  ]
}
```

3) Go to [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and copy the ***Project number***

4) In your Apps Script project Go to *Resources* -> *Cloud Platform project*, paste the previously copied ***Project number*** and click on *Set Project*.

5) Now, use this code I will provide you and I will explain its functions:

The `main` function will get and set the sheet's values. Notice I also added to the code a global JSON variable to build the requests to the [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api)

```
// JSON for the requests 
var options = {
  'headers': { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`},
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'method': '',
  'payload': ''
};

// This is the main function to run 
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var titleTranslation = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  var translation = Browser.inputBox(titleTranslation , 'Please enter the translation here:', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  var docUrl = createDocwithCode(translation);
  sheet.getRange(row, 6).setValue(docUrl);  
}
```

the `createDocwithCode` will allow you to create the Apps Script project that will be linked to your Doc.

```
// This will create the doc and link an Apps Script project
function createDocwithCode(translation){
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(translation);
  // Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
  options['method'] = "post";
  options['payload'] = JSON.stringify({ 'title': doc.getName(), 'parentId': doc.getId()});
  // Call the Apps Script API -> Method: projects.create
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects', options);
  addCodeToDoc(JSON.parse(res.getContentText()));
  return doc.getUrl();
}
```

the `addCodeToDoc` will fill the newly created Apps Script code with the desired content.

```
// Fill the previously Created Apps Script project with content 
function addCodeToDoc({scriptId, title}){
  // Make a PUT request with a JSON payload.
  options['method'] = "put";
  options['payload'] = JSON.stringify({ 
    "files": [
    {
      "name": title.replace(/\s+/g, ''),
      "type": "SERVER_JS",
      "source": createFunctionForDoc()
    },
    {
      "type": "JSON",
      "name": "appsscript",
      "source": "{\n  \"timeZone\": \"Europe/Paris\",\n  \"dependencies\": {\n  },\n  \"exceptionLogging\": \"STACKDRIVER\"\n}"
    } 
  ]
  })
  // Call the Apps Script API -> Method: projects.updateContent
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${scriptId}/content`, options);
}
```

Finally the `createFunctionForDoc` is a function to write future code in your newly created Apps Script code easily.

```
// Fill The Script with your desired funtions                     
function createFunctionForDoc(){
    return `
      function customFunction(){
        Logger.log("Hello World");
      }
    `
}
```

Your whole code will look like this one:

```
// JSON for the requests 
var options = {
  'headers': { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`},
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  'method': '',
  'payload': ''
};

// This is the main function to run 
function main() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  var titleTranslation = sheet.getRange(row, 3).getValue();
  var translation = Browser.inputBox(titleTranslation , 'Please enter the translation here:', Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL);
  var docUrl = createDocwithCode(translation);
  sheet.getRange(row, 6).setValue(docUrl);  
}


// This will create the doc and link an Apps Script project
function createDocwithCode(translation){
  var doc = DocumentApp.create(translation);
  // Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
  options['method'] = "post";
  options['payload'] = JSON.stringify({ 'title': doc.getName(), 'parentId': doc.getId()});
  // Call the Apps Script API -> Method: projects.create
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects', options);
  addCodeToDoc(JSON.parse(res.getContentText()));
  return doc.getUrl();
}

// Fill the previously Created Apps Script project with content 
function addCodeToDoc({scriptId, title}){
  // Make a PUT request with a JSON payload.
  options['method'] = "put";
  options['payload'] = JSON.stringify({ 
    "files": [
    {
      "name": title.replace(/\s+/g, ''),
      "type": "SERVER_JS",
      "source": createFunctionForDoc()
    },
    {
      "type": "JSON",
      "name": "appsscript",
      "source": "{\n  \"timeZone\": \"Europe/Paris\",\n  \"dependencies\": {\n  },\n  \"exceptionLogging\": \"STACKDRIVER\"\n}"
    } 
  ]
  })
  // Call the Apps Script API -> Method: projects.updateContent
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(`https://script.googleapis.com/v1/projects/${scriptId}/content`, options);
}

// Fill The Script with your desired funtions                     
function createFunctionForDoc(){
    return `
      function customFunction(){
        Logger.log("Hello World");
      }
    `
}
```

### Docs

There are the docs I used to help you

- [Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api)
- [Method: projects.create](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/create?apix_params=%7B%22resource%22%3A%7B%22parentId%22%3A%22YOUR-DOC-ID%22%2C%22title%22%3A%22YOUR-PROJECT-NAME%22%7D%7D)
- [Method: projects.updateContent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateContent?apix_params=%7B%22scriptId%22%3A%22YOUR-APPSCRIPT-ID%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22files%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22YOUR-GS-FILE-NAME%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22SERVER_JS%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22YOUR-CODE%22%7D%2C%7B%22type%22%3A%22JSON%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22appsscript%22%2C%22source%22%3A%22%7B%5Cn%20%20%5C%22timeZone%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22Europe%2FParis%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22dependencies%5C%22%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%7D%2C%5Cn%20%20%5C%22exceptionLogging%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22STACKDRIVER%5C%22%5Cn%7D%22%7D%5D%7D%7D)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)
- [Enabling script authorization and access](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes#setting_explicit_scopes